# how to give space between input text and button in table rows

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML Code like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span>Card No:&nbsp;</span>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <input id="BtnSave" type="button" value="Save" onclick="return BtnSave_onclick()" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

This all am keeping one Row of my table. I want to give space in between all my fields..

Am new in html and web applications.

Comment: Add margin: 0 5px 0 0; for input text

Comment: mam..can u edit my code with margin

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/fa742t4f/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use margins:

CSS:

```
span, input {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Inline:

```
<tr>
<td>
  <span style="margin:5px">Card No:&nbsp;</span>
  <input id="Text1" type="text" style="margin:5px" />
  <input id="BtnSave" type="button" style="margin:5px" value="Save" onclick="return BtnSave_onclick()" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Or, create a style.css file with these lines of code:

```
span, input {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

and include it in your project in your head section like this:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin`.

```
input {
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px; /* top right bottom left */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help,

```
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   span, input {
    margin: 5px;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <span>Card No:&nbsp;</span>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <input id="BtnSave" type="button" value="Save" onclick="return BtnSave_onclick()" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</body>
</html>
```